# Replace words and maintain case-sensitivity of the found string

Tags: php, regex, replace, case-sensitive

I am creating a php application to format files. So I need to apply a find-replace process while maintaining the case.

For example, I need to replace 'employees' with 'vehicles'.

```
$file_content = "Employees are employees_category MyEmployees kitEMPLOYEESMATCH";
$f = 'employees';
$r = 'vehicles';

echo str_ireplace($f, $r, $file_content);
```

Current Output:

```
vehicles are vehicles_category Myvehicles kitvehiclesMATCH
```

Desired Output:

```
Vehicles are vehicles_category MyVehicles kitVEHICLESMATCH
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48068407/2943403

Comment: Topically Related: [Replace string and preserve original string's case in the replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44450192/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this by replacing for each case separately:

```
<?php
     $file_content = "Employees are employees_category MyEmployees kitEMPLOYEESMATCH";
     $f = 'employees';
     $r = 'vehicles';

     $res = str_replace($f, $r, $file_content); // replace for lower case
     $res = str_replace(strtoupper($f), strtoupper($r), $res); // replace for upper case
     $res = str_replace(ucwords($f), ucwords($r), $res); // replace for proper case (capital in first letter of word)
     echo $res
   
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

While the SJ11's answer is attractive for its brevity, it is prone to making unintended replacements on already replaced substrings -- though not possible with the OP's sample data.

To ensure that replacements are not replaced, you must make only one pass over the input string.

For utility, I will include `preg_quote()`, so that pattern does not break when the `$r` value contains characters with special meaning in regex.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BsGGM)) ([PHP7.4 and up Demo](https://3v4l.org/4JINR)) ([PHP7.4 and up Demo with word boundaries](https://3v4l.org/srKeQ))

```
$file_content = "Employees are employees_category MyEmployees kitEMPLOYEESMATCH";
$f = 'employees';
$r = 'vehicles';

$pattern = '~('
           . implode(
               ')|(',
               [
                   preg_quote($f, '~'),
                   preg_quote(ucfirst($f), '~'),
                   preg_quote(strtoupper($f), '~')
               ]
           ) . ')~';
$lookup = [
    1 => $r,
    2 => ucfirst($r),
    3 => strtoupper($r)
];

var_export(
    preg_replace_callback(
        $pattern,
        function($m) use ($lookup) {
            return $lookup[count($m) - 1];
        },
        $file_content
    )
);
```

Output: (single quotes are from `var_export()`)

```
'Vehicles are vehicles_category MyVehicles kitVEHICLESMATCH'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mickmackusa - great solution but I needed a version to optionally only replace whole words so that for example when replacing the US spelling of "mom" with the UK spelling "mum" it didn't also replace "moment" with mument".

I also added a quick `str_contains()` check because I am using this function to replace a lot of words and I wanted to reduce regex time if the word doesn't exist at all first.

Here's a function I built based on your code to do this:

```
function replaceWithCase($source, $replacement, $string, $whole_word_only = false) {

    if(!str_contains(strtolower($string), strtolower($source))) return $string;

    $pattern = '~('
        . implode(
            ')|(',
            [
            preg_quote($source, '~'),
            preg_quote(ucfirst($source), '~'),
            preg_quote(strtoupper($source), '~')
            ]
        ) . ')~';

    if($whole_word_only) $pattern = '~\b(?:' . str_replace('~', '', $pattern) . ')\b~';

    $lookup = [
        1 => $replacement,
        2 => ucfirst($replacement),
        3 => strtoupper($replacement)
    ];

    $result =
        preg_replace_callback(
            $pattern,
            fn($m) => $lookup[array_key_last($m)],
            $string
        );

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: There are two problems with your extension of my script.  You have a forward slash (typo) in your wordboundary declaration.  And you aren't applying word boundaries to all alternations.  What your script break: https://3v4l.org/JlUCM

Comment: @mickmackusa - well that's embarrassing - I just discovered the issues in my application and came back to see your comment - wish I'd been notified about it! Thanks again though :) I've edited the above to fix things.

Comment: You can make your script more elegant (less verbose) if you write the word boundaries outside of a non-capturing parent group.  See how I've written `\b` only twice while constructing the pattern in the "PHP7.4 and up Demo with word boundaries" link in my answer.  You might even do: `if ($whole_word_only) { $pattern = '\b(?:' . $pattern . ')\b'; }` after `$pattern` is declared to avoid declaring `$word_boundary` at all.

Comment: I like the idea of a non-capturing group (I never think of these first), but I think for the second part of your idea, it would need to be: `if($whole_word_only) $pattern = '~\b(?:' . str_replace('~', '', $pattern) . ')\b~';` so that it moves the `~`s to the beginning and end of the expression.

Comment: Right, I forgot the pattern delimiters. Here's my final suggestion (I'll leave you alone :) ) https://3v4l.org/uRmFfW

Comment: Haha - all good :)
If we are getting silly, then there is this version (https://3v4l.org/6BQk7) which doesn't require the non-capturing parent if `$whole_word_only` is false. Perf tab seems to suggest that it might be slightly quicker (if you remove the `true`).